# Linux terminal - error: label at end of compound statement

Tags: c, linux, gcc, terminal, makefile

I'm using x64 Ubuntu Linux via VMware Player as a virtual machine. As a part of my project, I need to install some library (fec-3.0.1). I'm new to Linux and not good at coding.

Here is the error I encounter in **terminal** after successful configuration:

```
    farhat@ubuntu:~/project/fatcaps_v0.5/fec-3.0.1$ make
    gcc -g -O2 -I. -Wall    -c -o dotprod.o dotprod.c
    dotprod.c: In function ‘freedp’:
    dotprod.c:56:3: error: label at end of compound statement
       default:
       ^
    make: *** [dotprod.o] Error 1
```

Here is **function 'freedp'** content (the start line is 55):

```
    /* Free a dot product descriptor created earlier */
    void freedp(void *p){
      switch(Cpu_mode){
      case PORT:
      default:
    #ifdef __i386__
      case MMX:
      case SSE:
        return freedp_mmx(p);
      case SSE2:
        return freedp_sse2(p);
    #endif
    #ifdef __VEC__
      case ALTIVEC:
        return freedp_av(p);
    #endif
      }
    }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason why you meet the error `label at end of compound statement` is because the `default` case can not be empty, it means you must provide a `break` or `;` empty statement.

**Edited**: I find some material on that topic, and I got that: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-patches/2004-April/msg00235.html, It is the problem about the compiler gcc3.4, which reports an error on `default` without statements, and it is warning on gcc3.3, but now, I test on gcc4.8.2, it is all right....